# How to craft an SQL to create a report that selects all quotes with a certian line item, and to include another item if it is on that quote?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, report

I have two tables:  quote and item.

**quote table**

```
id | quote_number
---+-------
 1 |   100 
 2 |   200
```

**item table**

```
id | model | quote_id | other_data 
---+-------+----------+-----------
 1 |   ABC | 1        | xxx
 2 |  DISC | 1        | xxx
 3 |   ABC | 2        | xxx
 4 |  DISC | 2        | xxx
 3 |   XXX | 3        | xxx
 4 |  DISC | 3        | xxx
 3 |   ABC | 4        | xxx
```

I need to create a report to where I select all quotes that must contain the model `ABC` AND if they do, I also wish to list model `DISC` belonging to that quote.  I want to list all such item lines. How?

In plain English that would be "give me all quotes with model ABC on them that *may* also have the discount (DISC) associated with it".

**Example Report**

```
quote_id | model | other_data 
---------+-------+---------+-
 1       |   ABC | xxx
 1       |  DISC | xxx
 2       |   ABC | xxx
 2       |  DISC | xxx
```

So far I can only figure out how to pull lines with `ABC` in them, but I don't know how to pull in the lines with `DISC`, which have a condition of "must have ABC connected to the same quote".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could  use a subquery, You can use CTE's as well if you are using MySQL 8.0

```
SELECT it.quote_id, it.model, it.other_data
FROM item it INNER JOIN (
    SELECT quote_id 
    FROM item i WHERE model = 'ABC') as sub_it 
ON it.quote_id=sub_it.quote_id 
WHERE it.model='ABC' OR it.model='DISC'
ORDER BY it.quote_id DESC;
```

[DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/#&togetherjs=rQdnNwSLJT)

Answer (score 1):

`UNION ALL` seems like a good approach:

```
select ia.*
from items ia
where ia.model = 'ABC'
union all
select id.*
from items id
where id.model = 'DISC' and
      exists (select 1 from items ia where ia.quote_id = id.quote_id and ia.model = 'ABC')
order by quote_id, model;
```

This logic can take advantage of indexes on `items(model)` and `items(quote_id, model)`.  The `order by` would be needed for any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I vote for the sub query approach as the easiest and cleanest way to go.  I dislike using OR conditions so I've used an IN List instead.

```
   SELECT
        quote_id,
        model,
        other_data
     FROM item 
    Where  quote_id in ( SELECT quote_id FROM item i WHERE model = 'ABC' )
      AND  model IN ('ABC', 'DISC')
    ORDER BY 1,2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider the JOIN Statements:

```
SELECT quote_id, model, other_data FROM item i INNER JOIN quote q ON i.id = q.quote_id WHERE model = 'ABC' or model = 'DISC' ORDER BY quote_id DESC;
```

Comment: I am thinking that will include quotes that have DISC on them but without having ABC on them.  I do not need those quotes.  Only quotes with ABC on them that may or may not have DISC